# Is there a way to get the value of a property from msbuild?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, delphi, msbuild

If I use the command line to run msbuild like this: `msbuild myproject.dproj /t:Clean;Build /p:Config=Release /p:Platform=Win32` is there a way for the command line to get the value of where the actual exe of that command will be?

Comment: I think properties are accessed with `$()` e.g. `$(MSBuildToolsPath)` and can be be used in the msbuild xml.

Comment: I know that properties can be used like that but is there a way for the command line to read a particular value (i.e `DCC_ExeOutput`) for a given `$(Platform)\$(configuration)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly  you need. You want to read some property from file/environment variable and use it in a command line?

Comment: I want to read the output path as msbuild sees it when msbuild is passed the different platform/config values. MSBuild knows where to place the exe from the specifications either passed into it from the command line or the project options. Is there any way to pass what msbuild knows out to the command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should write a custom target to get that value.

**First**, add this target into the `myproject.dproj`：

```
<Target Name="GetOutputValue">  
<Message Importance="high" Text="$(DCC_ExeOutput)"></Message>
</Target>
```

**Then**, directly use this command to invoke the `GetOutputValue` target to get that value.

```
msbuild myproject.dproj /t:GetOutputValue
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In my searching I ran across Inline Tasks like you are describing and ended up using the built in `WriteLinesToFile` task described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/writelinestofile-task?view=vs-2019